# Foreach nested through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays.I need iterate through this arrays and create new one.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$lines = array(
array(0,0,0,0,0),
array(2,2,2,2,2),
array(0,1,2,1,0),
array(2,1,2,1,2)

);

$indexes = array(2,3,4,5,6);

foreach($lines as $l => $line) {

foreach($line as $d => $val) {
    foreach($indexes as $i => $index) {
       if($val == 0) {
          $simbols[$l][$i] = $index - 1;
       } else if ($val == 2) {
          $simbols[$l][$i] = $index + 1;
       } else {
          $simbols[$l][$i] = $index;
      }
   }
}
}
var_dump($simbols);

?>
```

From this code I got this result:

```
 $simbols = array(
      array(1,2,3,4,5),
      array(3,4,5,6,7),
      array(1,2,3,4,5),
      array(3,4,5,6,7)
  );
```

But, I expected next:

```
   $simbols = array(
      array(1,2,3,4,5),
      array(3,4,5,6,7),
      array(1,3,5,5,5),
      array(3,3,5,5,7)
  );
```

How I can achieve this results ?

Comment: please ellabortate on the what and why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this -

```
foreach($indexes as $i=>$index) {
    foreach($lines as $l=>$val) {
        if($val[$i] == 0) {
            $simbols[$l][$i] = $index - 1;
        } else if ($val[$i] == 2) {
            $simbols[$l][$i] = $index + 1;
        } else {
            $simbols[$l][$i] = $index;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($simbols);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exact what I wont to achieve!